# How do I calculate the energy density of a flywheel rotating along dual axes?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, precession

It seems to me that if you can rotate a flywheel along more than one axis simultaneously you can significantly add to the amount energy it can store.

So a flywheel that is spinning and precessing(?) at a 1 to 1 ratio how would you calculate its energy density?

Comment: Just to clarify: What do you mean by 1 to 1 ratio? Do you mean that the rotational speed in $\omega /s$ of the wheel about its axis is the same as its precession angular rotational speed?

Comment: Sorry it took so long to answer. Computer was down. Yes. Robert Chester calls such orbits Quasi-Spherical Orbits or QSOs. He refers to a ratio when talking about the rotational speed vs the precession speed. That's where I got that from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I offer the calculation of energy for a disc precessing under gravity. Assuming a precessing disc as in [Feinman's Figure 20.5](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_20.html), you have to consider both the rotational energy equations and the precession energy equations.

Energy considerations, assuming the non-disc parts of the system have negligible mass:
$$E_{total} = E_s + E_p = {1\over2}I_s\omega_s^2+{1\over2}Mv_p^2 \tag1$$
Where $E_s$ and $E_p$ are the spin and precession energies respectively. $\omega_s$ and $\omega_p$ are spin angular velocity and the precession angular velocity respectively. $I_s$ is the angular momentum of the disc about its spin axis, and $M$ is the mass of the disc. Simplifying:

$$E_{total}={1\over2}Mr_s^2\omega_s^2+{1\over2}Mr_p^2\omega_p^2 \tag2$$

Where $r$ denotes the respective rotational radii. Therefore energy density (energy per unit mass) is:
$$E_{density} = {1\over2}(r_s^2\omega_s^2 + r_p^2\omega_p^2) \tag3$$

Next you can consider your constraints in terms of precession rate vs spin rate. In torque-induced precession (as below when gravity $g$ is present), precession angular velocity (where $\theta$ is the angle to the horizontal during precession) is:
$$\omega_p = {Mgr_p\over L_s} = {Mgr_pcos\theta\over I_s\omega_s} = {Mgr_pcos\theta\over {1\over2}Mr_s^2\omega_s} = {2gr_pcos\theta\over r_s^2\omega_s} \tag4$$

If $w_s = \omega_p$ and the $r_p$ is measured relative to the horizontal ($cos\theta = 1$):
$${r_s^2\over r_p} = 2g \tag5$$

Equation $5$ can be substituted into equation $3$, as well as set $\omega_s = \omega_p$ in equation $3$ for simplification.

Comment: Note that a flywheel precessing under gravity is a bit of a dangerous system to actually extract energy from. In order for it to precess under gravity, the flywheel must be basically free; if you extract energy by slowing down the flywheel, without also moving it back toward the center of precession, there's a good chance you'll make it unstable, and an unstable industrial flywheel is not something you ever want to be in the path of.

Comment: @probably_someone ...For the model used (Feinman's figure quoted in the answer), it is possible to extract energy while precession continues, without instability. As long as your energy extraction component (say extraction by magnetic induction by a non spinning part on the spinning axis of the wheel), extraction would decrease the spin speed, but increase precession speed. Energy addition would increase spin speed, but decrease precession speed.

Comment: @Dlamini  Thank you very much. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: @probably_someone I'm aware of stability issues, although I'm not sure we're talking about the same type of flywheel.

Comment: @QuincyScott Yeah, I was thinking of a different kind, more like a precessing top than a gyroscope held horizontally.